# Выборка изображения из БД

Tags: mysql, php, html, css, база-данных

Люди, помогите превратить вот эту строчку:

```
<?php echo $mail ['avatar']; ?>
```

Вот в эту:

```
<img src='$avatar' />
```

А то выборка рисунка идет как текст. А надо, чтобы все было как в верхней строчке, но чтобы было рисунком.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А что находится в $mail['avatar']?
Относительный к серверу путь к картинке?:

```
    img src='<?php=$mail['avatar'];?>' /
```

Абсолютный путь картинки на сервере (к примеру /var/www/path/file.ext)?:

```
   Примерно так тогда (обрезаем абсолютный путь и оставляем относительный): 
   img src='<?php=str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$mail['avatar']);?>'/
```

Находится сама картинка?:

```
    Надо знать тип хранимых данных (примерно так для gif):img src='data:image/gif;base64,<?php=base64_encode($mail['avatar']);?>'/
```

P.S.: Задайте вопрос корректнее! Хотя думаю Вы получили ответ в 1 пункте!